# UPDATE with nested query in PostgreSQL with unwanted results

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Due to its geographic capabilities I'm migrating my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and SQL that used to be so trivial is now are becoming painfully slow to overcome.

In this case I use a nested query to obtain the results in two columns, having in 1st column an ID and in the 2nd a counting result and insert those results in table1.
EDIT: This is the original MySQL working code that I need to be working in PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY id
) AS c ON c.id = table1.id
SET table1.cnt = c.cnt
```

The result is having all rows with the same counting result, that being the 1st counting result of the nested select.
In MySQL this would be solved easily.
How would this work in PostgreSQL?
Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the `ASC`, since the subquery is linked anyway. You do need a correlation name for the outer query, though.

Comment: Can you write the MySQL version that would solve that "easily"?

Comment: Thanks horse. On second thought, my answer would not have exist at all.

Comment: To the OP: please add your _intentions_ to the question, since we don't all understand mysql semantics here.

Comment: To make it more clear I have those 2 tables e.g. in a photo project.
Table1 is the Photographer's table with ID column and num_of_photos column with the number of pictures that guy has in the database (listed in table 2).
Table2 in the Photo's table with having e.g. its id, filename and photographer_id as foreign key pointing to id in Photographer's table.
The posted code for MySQL in the question counts how many photos each photographer has in table2 and updates that value in num_of_photos column in table1.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1 dst
SET cnt = src.cnt
FROM (SELECT id, COUNT (*) AS cnt
     FROM table2 
     GROUP BY id) as src
WHERE src.id = dst.id
;
```

Comment: I've edited my SQL code in the question to show the original MySQL working code, instead of the postgresql problematic code for the sake of clarity. But thank you for your answer. I apreciate your help.

Comment: That's fair enough. But -as I said- not all postgres/SQL people understand the underlying semantics involved.